# Cannot create objects with whileloop (python)

Tags: python, class, object

im trying to create a bunch of Parts objects from another class, and it doesn't seem to be working. Im reading the txt file correctly, which is just this if u guys need it:

```
 partA 22.50 60
 partB 595.00 100
 partC 1.95 1000
 partD 899.95 100
 partE 10.95 100
```

The problem is occuring when under the #fills parts--------------------- comment under the parts inventory class. the print statement wont work.

```
class Parts:  
    def __init__(self, partname, price, quantity):
        self.partName = partname
        self.partPrice = price
        self.partQuantity = quantity

    def getpartname(self):
        return self.partName

    def getpartprice(self):
        return self.partPrice

    def getpartquantity(self):
        return self.partQuantity

    def setpartname(self, name):
        self.partName = name

    def setpartprice(self, price):
        self.partPrice = price

    def setpartquantity(self, quantity):
        self.partQuantity = quantity

    def equals(self, part2):
        if self.partName == part2:
            return True


class PartInventory:  # constructer, getter setter, dictionary
    def __init__(self):
        self.partInventoryy={}
        partnames = []
        partprices = []
        partqs = []
        partfile = open("parts.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
        #fills dictionary----------------------------------------------------
        for line in partfile:
            substring = line.split(' ')
            partnames.append(substring[0])
            partprices.append(substring[1])
            partqs.append(substring[2].strip("\n"))
        self.partInventoryy=dict(zip(partnames, partqs))
        partPricings = dict(zip(partnames, partprices))
        print(self.partInventoryy)
        #fills parts--------------------------------------------------------
        i=0
        while i<len(partnames):
            partnames[i]= Parts(partnames[i],partprices[i],partqs[i])
            i=i+1
        print(partE.getpartname())
    #methods---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: By "The print statement won't work"... Do you mean that it is not printing out anything or it is throwing an exception?  I am guessing it isn't printing anything and you think it should be printing out something?

Comment: says NameError: name 'partE' is not defined

Comment: should be printing out partE. i know this accessor method is redundant but its just for a test

Comment: Well it seems as if you never instantiated partE... I do not see a line like "partE  = None" or "partE = Part(..." did you want like the first part out of the partInventory? or were you looking for a Part with a particular name?

Comment: did you try self.getpartname()? or rather, I guess this is the part Inventory so it doesn't have that method... but, you could do:  self.partInventory[0].getPartName()

Comment: come to think of it... the while loop isn't making much sense to me.  It seems like you are iterating over the partnames array and then instantiating a Part and assigning it to the partnames array.  Did you intend to assign to the partInventory instead?

Comment: sorry im confused to what you're asking. im just trying to create part objects from reading in a txt file, and using a getpartnamemethod to check if they were indeed created. if youre bored http://puu.sh/lKLSd/bf486b28e9.png this is what im supposed to do

Comment: I would trim the code down as much as possible to start with... why not instantiate a new Part object when iterating over the lines of the file?  That gets ride of your three string arrays and the while loop.  The error that you are seeing though is because you are trying to access a method on an object that you never created.  PartE does not exist because you never created a variable named PartE.  If partE is in the inventory, then you need to search for it or access it by index.

Comment: well the parts inventory has to have a local data structure so i need the lists. im not supposed to do this the most efficent way, my prof just wants to make sure i know how to work with classes/objects

Comment: "why not instantiate a new Part object when iterating over the lines of the file?" thats what im trying to do :D

Comment: Well, I would create a "getpartname" method in the inventory class that iterates over the partinventory and returns the Part object associated with the name of the part that is passed in as a parameter.  Then you should be able to call "self.getpartname('partE') from the partInventory class.

Comment: By the time you get to the while loop, you have already iterated over all of the lines in the file.

Comment: is this for the print statement?  "self.getpartname('partE').  by the way thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: "If partE is in the inventory, then you need to search for it or access it by index. " how am i not accessing it by index? "partnames[i] "looks like its accessing an index to me

Comment: In that while loop, you are not accessing by index... you are assigning by index.  That line literally reads:  "Set the item at Index Location 'i' in the 'partnames' array equal to a new Parts Object with values: partnames[i], partprices[i], partqs[i]"... this means that you are assigning as opposed to accessing.  This doesn't seem to make sense because you had already filled up the partnames array when you were iterating over the lines in the file... Now, in the while loop, you are basically replacing string items in the partnames array with Parts items.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Part` objects are being created just fine.

The problem is you are trying to access something that you never created -- `PartE`.  For comparison, some variables you did create:

- `partnames`
- `partprices`
- `partqs`
- `partfile`
- `line`
- `i`
- `substring`

---

To prove to yourself that you are creating stuff in the while loop, add one more line to it:

```
    while i<len(partnames):
        partnames[i]= Parts(partnames[i],partprices[i],partqs[i])
        i=i+1
        print(partnames[i])
```

This will print every `Parts` you create.